# jQuery UI datepicker - Trying to capture click event from date clicked

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

We're using jquery UI 1.8.23 at my workplace.

How can I capture the date clicked in datepicker, so I can format the current date into a datestamp and pass that value into a hidden form field?

Here's some code I've tried to get working:

```
$('.ui-state-default').live('click', function(){
    console.log('date clicked');
    var currentdate = $(this).text();
    var d = currentdate;
    var m = monthFormat($('.ui-datepicker-month').text());
    var y = $('.ui-datepicker-year').text();
    $('a.ui-state-default').removeClass('ui-state-highlight');
    $(this).addClass('ui-state-highlight');

    if (currentdate.length < 2) {
    d = "0" + currentdate;
    }
    var datestamp = y + "-" + m + "-" + d;
    console.log(datestamp);
    $('#dateHidden').val(datestamp);
});
```

Thanks for looking at my code I appreciate any help you guys can offer.

Comment: Why aren't you using the onSelect event? http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You don't need to do anything to format the date. The `DatePicker` widget does it for you.
Just use the `altField` and `altFormat` properties:

```
$("#myDatePicker").datepicker({
    // The hidden field to receive the date
    altField: "#dateHidden",
    // The format you want
    altFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    // The format the user actually sees
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
    onSelect: function (date) {
        // Your CSS changes, just in case you still need them
        $('a.ui-state-default').removeClass('ui-state-highlight');
        $(this).addClass('ui-state-highlight');
    }
});
```

Documentation:

http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-altField

http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-altFormat

Demonstration:

http://jsfiddle.net/sFBn2/10/

Comment: and how is that outputting a value to a hidden field?

Comment: It does it automatically. That's what the `altField` is there for.

Comment: OK but how can I tell if the value is being passed to the hidden field if Chrome developer tools doesn't update during the onSelect event?

Comment: Check the jsFiddle I've added to the answer.

Comment: Works fine as a standalone fiddle but the hidden field is added using append() and the id is different. Here's my fork http://jsfiddle.net/bitmapshades/LFpwN/2/

Comment: One solution doesn't fit all scenarios. The answer is based on the question scenario. If you're adding elements dynamically to the DOM, of course you'll need do adapt the solution. I use this on every single `ASP.NET` project I have. Both `WebForms` and `MVC`, with fixed HTML markup or self generated. It never failed. The documentation is on the post. Also, the `jQuery` selector isn't based just on elements IDs. You have thousands of ways to use it.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#calendar').datepicker({
        inline: true,
        firstDay: 1,
        changeMonth: false,
        changeYear: true,
        showOtherMonths: true,
        showMonthAfterYear: false,
        yearRange: "2015:2025",      
        dayNamesMin: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
        onSelect: function (date) {
            alert(date);
        }
    });
```

Comment: You should add a description to your solution.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery **`Datepicker`** gives the option of *formatting date*.  So why don't you make use of that?

```
$('element').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' });
```

Also you don't need of a separate method to capture the click event.  You the default method `onSelect`

```
$('input').datepicker({
 dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    onSelect: function (date) {
    //defined your own method here
    alert(date);
    }
})
```

Check this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/SvFAA/10/)

Comment: all that does is set the attribute class="hasDatepicker" on the hidden field. (I didn't down vote you myself).

Comment: @bitmapshades You're trying to assign the value to an hidden field.  I could not get what you're trying to add datepicker class?Correct me if I was wrong.

Comment: I wasn't even aware that I needed to use the datepicker class to capture a click event with the datepicker component until today but thanks for chiming in.

Comment: @bitmapshades I'm glad I was able to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Your datepicker listens that.

see [onSelect() function](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect)

> > Called when the datepicker is selected. The function receives the selected date as text and the datepicker instance as parameters. this refers to the associated input field.

```
$('.date-pick').datepicker( {
    onSelect: function(date) {
        //play with date here
    },
----
----
---
```