# jQuery UI datepicker - Trying to output date to an appended field using onSelect

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

We're using jquery UI 1.8.23 at my workplace. I previously asked about this but I'm no further forward:
[jQuery UI datepicker - Trying to capture click event from date clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18640143/jquery-ui-datepicker-trying-to-capture-click-event-from-date-clicked)

How can I capture the date in onSelect and pass the value to a field which has been appended with jQuery to the search form.

```
$('#search-form').append('<input id="dateHidden" name="dateHidden" type="text" />');

$('#datepicker2').click(function(){
    $('#ui-datepicker-div').append('<form><input id="selectMonth" type="button" value="Whole month"></form>');
});

$('#datepicker2').datepicker({
    // The hidden field to receive the date
    altField: "#dateHidden",
    // The format you want
    altFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    // The format the user actually sees
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
    onSelect: function (date) {
        $('a.ui-state-default').removeClass('ui-state-highlight');
        $(this).addClass('ui-state-highlight');
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bitmapshades/LFpwN/7/

Thanks for looking at my code I appreciate any help you guys can offer.

Comment: Duplicate of [jQuery UI datepicker - Trying to capture click event from date clicked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18640143/jquery-ui-datepicker-trying-to-capture-click-event-from-date-clicked) – please don’t start new questions in cases like this, but append more info to your original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your HTML markup, both on the page and the Javascript side:

**HTML**

```
<!-- The tag wasn't closed and you can't have the class 'hasDatePicker' set beforehand -->
<input type="text" name="datePicker" id="datepicker2" />
```

**Javascript**

```
// The input tag wasn't closed here either
$('#search-form').append('<input id="dateHidden" name="date" type="hidden" />');
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LFpwN/9/

Comment: The datepicker and the class "hasDatepicker"  is added by the custom jquery ui script I didn't include it in the fiddle because the function is too large for demo purposes.

Comment: The html markup is just a small snippet from the DOM inspector for that form.

Comment: I see. But if the input has this class before the DatePicker is called, it won't attach the widget to the input. After I removed the stuff from the generated code, it's working.

Comment: On the demo you can see that setting the altField to a previously dynamically added element works just fine. As far as the element is actually added.

Comment: I was typing a reply looking at it now.

Comment: Yes tried it and updated with my fork: http://jsfiddle.net/bitmapshades/Js2AE/
Something else must be breaking it locally.

Comment: Yes. It's working like it should. Do you have any errors on the console?

Comment: I get one error: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'onload'
(anonymous function) but there's other scripts running on the page which might break I'm on a different git branch than master.