# Detecting when a hidden form field was changed dynamically

Tags: javascript, forms, dynamic, field, dynamically-generated

How can we detect when a hidden form field was changed dynamically? If it was changed, then display an alert?

A JQuery UI (DatePicker) is used to change the hidden form field.

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({altField: "#alternate", altFormat: "yymmdd"}).$('#alternate').trigger('change');


<input name="textbox" id="alternate" type="hidden" size="30" 
onchange="alert('changed')" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it with help from two similar questions on StackOverflow.com

1. [jQuery UI datepicker - Trying to capture click event from date clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18640143/jquery-ui-datepicker-trying-to-capture-click-event-from-date-clicked)
2. [jQuery - Detect value change on hidden input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6533087/jquery-detect-value-change-on-hidden-input-field?rq=1)

---

```
<input name="textbox" id="alternate" type="hidden" size="30" 
onchange="alert('changed')" />


<script>
$(function() {
    $("#myDatePicker").datepicker({
        // The hidden field to receive the date
        altField: "#alternate",
        // The format for the date
        altFormat: "yymmdd",
        onSelect: function (date) {
            // trigger the .change() event
            $('#alternate').trigger('change');
        }
    })
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#alternate').change(function(){
    window.alert('Change has happened.  Ya dig?');
});
```

Comment: Do I need a handler for the hidden field? How will the browser know when the HIDDEN field is changed? Basically, how can I use your code to make this happen?

Comment: I learned on Stack Overflow, that, changes in value to hidden elements don't automatically fire the .change() event. So, wherever it is that I am setting that value, I also have to tell jQuery to trigger it. But the datepicker sets the value. Any idea how to tell datepicker to trigger the .change() event?